# Questionário à comunidade

Tags: debate, perguntas, comportamento

Encontro-me a desenvolver um projeto de software à título pessoal, e porque o mesmo é também dedicado a autores de softwares e ou programadores e como membro desta comunidade, gostaria de saber da melhor maneira de solicitar por esta via o preenchimento de um questionário sobre temáticas que o mesmo aborda ou saber se este tipo de situação não é aceitável.

Comment: Põe o link aqui em comentário.

Comment: sim pensei nisso... mas não quero ferir as regras da comunidade!

Comment: Normalmente esse tipo de coisa não é permitida, mas não é uma regra absoluta que não pode, de maneira alguma, ser violada. Se a comunidade se sentir disposta a ajudar, sinta-se à vontade para adicionar uma resposta com o link e instruções.

Comment: Ver: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2403/h%c3%a1-alguma-%c3%a1rea-aqui-no-so-pt-para-pesquisas-acad%c3%aamicas-cientificas. E você pode convidar as pessoas livremente no [chat].

Comment: obrigado pelas respostas prontas. vou então seguir as recomendações.

Comment: @JorgeB. já tenho os questionários prontos... acabei de ver o seu perfil e vejo que desenvolve para android...tem muita experiência?

Comment: Tenho 2 anos de experiência em Android porque?

Comment: @JorgeB. tenho de construir um aplicativo para integrar com o sistema que estou a desenvolver... android, iphone e windows phone... mas para começar estava a pensar fazer em android como base para os outros...um modelo. e estava a pensar pedir umas opiniões fundamentadas.

Comment: Pensa em utilizar phonegap que é multi plataforma.

Comment: @JorgeB. não conhecia. vou estudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seguimento dos comentários que obtive a esta minha pergunta, venho deixar aqui dois questionários que gostava de ver respondido pela comunidade. Trata-se de dois estudos que estou a realizar sobre um protejo que desenvolvo...

Sobre gestão de ativos digitais: http://goo.gl/forms/p5861xICMc

Porquê à comunidade? Porque como elemento participativo na medida do possível e porque este segundo questionário é mais direccionado para programadores, webdesigners e ou titulares de obras de software...solicito mais um minuto do vosso tempo para:

Licenciamento de software e autenticação: http://goo.gl/forms/wZLoMtYCG9

Todos os comentários são bem vindos. Cada questionário tem um campo específico para o efeito.

Obrigado